# Twitter Deep linking is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, twitter, deep-linking

We have implemented twitter app card in our web site for twitter deep linking

```
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="myappiphone://section/category/url/"/>
<meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="398563536"/>
<meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="MyAppiPhone"/>

<meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="myappipad://section/category/url/"/>
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="390847874"/>
<meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="MyAppiPad"/>
```

both iPhone and iPad cards working properly and displaying link to launch our app in twitter app but when tried to launch our app and i am getting complete url **"myappiphone://section/category/url/"** in the method **application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:** but in case of iPad app i am getting only url scheme **"myappipad://"**.

can you please help me out what's the problem, where i m getting wrong.